# How to change the output name of index.template.html in Flash Builder?

Tags: flash, flash-builder

Ok, when I compile my action script project in Flash Builder 4 it creates a html wrapper file based on index.template.html in my html-template folder. That file automatically gets the name of my project or main application (project name.html). But usually I want it to have the name index.html.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

open up index.template.html and copy all the code.
create a new file in html-template dir called index.html
Open up index.html and paste the code from the template


[EDIT]
Right click on the src folder
and create a new application
label it index

I didn't suggest this before because its not as clean as the other method but I guess that didn't work. This method however I know works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That does create an index.html in my build folder, but it is left unchanged, meaning that it still has its placeholder tags in it like: ${bgcolor} and ${swf}. I want it to be treated as the template OR the template to just have a different name than the main Class.

Comment: That's odd I was pretty sure It replaces the preprocessor commands on any file.